# Can I safely stack a chest freezer on top of a heat pump dryer?

Tags: kitchens, dryer, freezer

I live in London, UK where space is gold dust. My galley style kitchen does not have space for a freezer and dryer side by side. My only option is to stack them on top using those stacking kits. Is that something I can do?

Comment: Is the freezer a front door type or top opening?  You want enough space on top of the dryer for ventilation.  A top opening freezer will require a ladder/stairs to get into.

Comment: Make sure the freezer, fuuly loaded, does not exceed the weight carrying capacity of the dryer.

Comment: Have you considered stacking the dryer on the clothes washer, instead? In the US, those are usually the pair that are stacked.

Comment: @FreeMan the washer may be the same thing as the dryer. Some of those other side of the Atlantic people have single machines that are both washer and dryer somehow. They're for narrowboats.

Comment: May be so, @Harper-ReinstateMonica. Until the OP clarifies, we won't know...

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to literally stacking the freezer *on* the dryer, consider a steel shelving/racking solution. This would provide a way of carrying the weight of the freezer and its contents to the floor *without placing any burden on the cabinet of the dryer.* It also allows you to preserve an arbitrary amount of clearance around the dryer's cabinet.

A steel shelf is rather.. commercial-looking amidst home decor, so you may have to exercise some creativity to conceal it!

Double rivet style is nice because it offers a degree of adaptability. You could install the four horizontal rails to create the shelf holding the freezer, for example, and then install only the two sides and rear pieces at floor level (omitting the one across the front). This would gain some stability in the legs while avoiding the front section which might be unsightly or in the way crossing in front of the washer. <sub>Image credit: [there](https://blog.shelving.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Double-Rivet.jpg)</sub>

[image: double rivet shelf]

Maybe I'm a shelving nut.. I don't buy it from home centers or big box stores where it comes in a kit that's different from (incompatible with) every other shelf kit they've ever sold before. Instead I buy the parts from a local industrial material handling shop. I've been buying the same RiveTier brand parts from them for 20+ years, a few posts here, a couple sets of horizontal supports there, and it all works together. Maybe there's a similar supplier near you.

Comment: Then again, "industrial chic" is a design theme, so maybe that'll work!